# move dynamically uploaded files in asp

Tags: asp-classic

I am having a application that uploads files according to the user input..i just want to move that particular file to moved to another folder..

Now i am able to move the files to the destination folder..but it moves all the files which is already there in the folder..

i am creating a folder dynamically while uploading the files..and i need that file to be moved to that created folder...

I need to move only the uploaded file during run time...

```
E:\Export Documents - Copy\Uploads this path to C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

this is my code

```
Set oFS = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strDir = "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\" & fldr 
oFS.CopyFile "E:\Export Documents - Copy\Uploads\*.jpg", "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\" & fldr
```

Comment: Please don't delete your questions after you get help, this is not personal help forum. If something helped you to solve the problem mark it as accepted to mark the question as resolved and let it be. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is identify the file you have just uploaded and then move that. If you are already creating a folder to store the files in in inetpub, you might as well do the same in Uploads, and then just move that folder.

You will probably find it helpful to use fileSystemObject.MoveFolder instead of .CopyFile so that your Uploads folder does not fill up.

If you want some help with how to do that, post the code you are using to upload your file.

For working with the FileSystemObject, this is a [useful reference](http://www.bettersolutions.com/vba/VVZ200/MO747843531.htm)

On another note, is it really wise to move files from Uploads into wwwroot? A malicious user could do some damage in there.

Comment: Thank you so much..i did what you said..i just did the same as well as in uploads..

Comment: is it possible to send uploaded file as an attachment in email

Comment: It is, but that's another question. Have a look at CDOSYS. Also perhaps consider sending an email with a link to the location of the uploaded file on a website, as that will be smaller and easier to do.